# Method for the pattern: "if (obj is Abc && (obj as Abc) ...)"

Tags: c#

Here's two simple classes:

```
class Abc { public int x; }
class Bcd { public int y; }
```

Given that `obj` is of type `object`, here's a couple of examples of testing for `Abc` or `Bcd` with certain characteristics:

```
if (obj is Abc && (obj as Abc).x > 0 && Math.Pow((obj as Abc).x, 2) > 100)
    Console.WriteLine(123);

if (obj is Bcd && (obj as Bcd).y > 0 && Math.Pow((obj as Bcd).y, 2) > 100)
    Console.WriteLine(234);
```

What's a good way to deal with this pattern of:

```
if (obj is Abc && (obj as Abc).SomePropertyOrMethod && ...
```

One approach is an `Is` extension method:

```
public static bool Is<T>(this object obj, Func<T, bool> pred) where T : class
    => (obj is T) && pred(obj as T);
```

With this, the above examples can be written as:

```
if (obj.Is<Abc>(abc => abc.x > 0 && Math.Pow(abc.x, 2) > 100))
    Console.WriteLine(123);

if (obj.Is<Bcd>(bcd => bcd.y > 0 && Math.Pow(bcd.y, 2) > 100))
    Console.WriteLine(234);
```

In this way the `(obj as ...)` expressions are not repeated.

Are there other approaches to this pattern?

This [pattern matching proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/206) seems like it would handle this well (see section 8.1).

Comment: In C# 6 you can use the `?.` operator like so: `((x as Abc)?.x > 0)`

Comment: @Blorgbeard wouldn't that generate a `bool?` which can't be used as argument for the `if`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Try passing `(obj as Abc).x` to `Math.Pow` :-)

Comment: I think you should add second type parameter `TBase` to `Is` with restriction `T: TBase`. Use it instead of obj. Type inference allows you to call it like `obj.is((Bcd bcd) => ...`

Comment: @usr It looks like the `?.` does not need to go on and protect the `>` operator since the `>` will not explode on `null`. Comparing a "null" value of `int?` (`HasValue` is false) to the value `0` of type `int?` (`HasValue` is true, and `Value` is zero) with a **lifted** operator `>` returns the value `false` of non-nullable `bool` type.

Answer (score 5):

I feel this takes a simple thing and makes it complicated. Also the namespace pollution resulting from extending `object` isn't nice. Further, this is a misuse of `as`. This should be a throwing cast (e.g. `((Abc)obj)`) because we expect the cast to always succeed. A throwing cast has an assertion and a nice exception for that built-in. It's documenting the fact that this is expected to succeed.

An alternative would be to declare a variable:

```
var abc = obj as Abc;
if (abc != null && abc.x > 0 && Math.Pow(abc.x, 2) > 100)
    Console.WriteLine(123);
```

Seems simple enough. I see no problems with that.

That said the extension method approach can be useful in places where you cannot easly declare a variable, for example in certain queries or in deeply nested expressions. That's generally undesirable but it sometimes happens.

Comment: This is the way you should do it, because `is` is extremely expensive, as expensive as `as`. Doing it twice every time sounds extremely painful in a tight loop (and without a tight loop who cares, do what you want!)

Comment: @dharmatech the failing cast would be guarded by an `is` check like you are doing it now. Just replace `as` by `(Abc)`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what's best/worst but `(obj as Abc).x` may end up in `NullReferenceException` if the cast fails. One way I see is breaking down the condition check like below:

```
Abc a = obj as Abc;
if (a != null && a.x > 0 && Math.Pow(a.x, 2) > 100)
    Console.WriteLine(123);
```

That way, no need of checking the condition `obj is Abc` since `a != null` will be `true` only when `obj as Abc` casting successes.

Answer (score 0):

Add some static checking:

```
public static bool Is<T, TBase>(this TBase obj, Func<T, bool> pred)
    where TBase : class
    where T : class, TBase
{
    var t = obj as T;
    return t != null && pred(t);
}
```

Use like this:

```
TypeBase obj;
...
if (obj.Is((TypeA obj) => ...))
```

Comment: The version of `Is` in the question also handles the inference case. I.e. this works: `if (obj.Is((Abc abc) => abc.x > 0)) Console.WriteLine(345);`